# Convert this SQL query to mongodb query -

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB so I need help to create a mongo query from below SQL query. I am also trying to create a MongoDB query which is similar to MySQL query.

```
//SQL
SELECT *
FROM SUMMARY
WHERE STATUS=? AND ENDTIME < (NOW() - interval 15 MINUTE)

// MongoDB
db.trip.find({
    "status": "CONNECTION_LOST",
    "endTime": {
        "$lt" : dateDifference : {
            $subtract: [ new Date(), 15*60*1000 ] 
        }
    } 
})
```

Below is the mongo document related to trip and dates are in ISO format

```
[
  {

    "_id" : ObjectId("59b009af802f927038ee05e6"),
    "tripNum" : 644358,
    "startTime" : ISODate("2017-07-20T10:21:11Z"),
    "endTime" : "ISODate("2017-07-20T10:45:11Z"),
    "status" : "CONNECTION_LOST"
  },
  {

    "_id" : ObjectId("59b009erf802f9er38ee05e6"),
    "tripNum" : 644359,
    "startTime" : ISODate("2017-07-20T10:55:11Z"),
    "endTime" : ISODate("2017-07-20T11:21:11Z"),
    "status" : "CONNECTION_LOST"
  }
]
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must convert the date calculation result into the `Date` (`ISODate`) object.

Query example:

```
db.trip.find({
    "status": "CONNECTION_LOST",
    "endTime": { "$lt": new Date(new Date() - 15*60*1000) }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Run The Below Command In Mongodb Console :

`var endDate=new Date()`

Then Try Below Code :

`db.trip.find({"status": "CONNECTION_LOST",endTime:{$gte:new Date(endDate-15*60*1000),$lt:endDate}})`

Comment: endDate field is not there. Tried using endTime but getting syntax error

Comment: db.trip.find({"status": "CONNECTION_LOST",endTime:{$gte:new Date(endTime-15*60*1000),$lt:new Date()}})
2017-12-19T08:38:39.864+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] ReferenceError: endTime is not defined :